# Calibrating tea dosage

Tags: tea, concentration

How can I get the right strength of tea?

I recently have been trying Gyokura Imperial, a Japanese tea, experimentally, but it is hard to know whether I have the dosage correct because I don't know what it's supposed to taste like.

I guess if I had a color card maybe, but it would have to be for this particular type of tea, which has a somewhat yellowish color.

Comment: If you do a Google search on Gyokuro Imperial Tea, you will find a ton of information about the tea, how to brew, etc. I did an image search also and it seems that brewed, most were a pale yellow or pale green color. (Gyokuro is a green tea.)

Answer (score 1):

[O-Cha.com says that](https://www.o-cha.com/brew-gyokuro.html) a good ratio is 1g of tea leaves to 30g (i.e. 30mL) of water.

Also keep in mind that, since Gyokuro is such a delicate tea, you want to brew with water that's between 120º and 140º F (50º to 60º C). This is much, much lower than regular black or green teas.

Comment: What are the consequences of brewing it too hot?

Comment: Green teas tend to get bitter and fishy when you brew them too hot.

Comment: wow 120-140 F is really really low, I've never tried that with any tea. Except when I'm 'cold-brewing'.